# Jsoup java не подгружаются некоторые элементы

Tags: java, jsoup

Парсю [сайт](https://cheb.media/azs/) с ценами на бензин , вот мой код:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(BENZ_URL).userAgent(userAgent).get();
    Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("grid-item");

    for (Element element : elements) {
        Elements ai98 = element.select("div[class=item ai98]");
        System.out.println(ai98.toString());

    }
```

В браузере div с ценами отображается корректно:

```html
<div class="item ai98">
<div class="price">
<div class="int d5"></div>
<div class="int d0"></div>
<div class="int dot"></div>
<div class="int d3"></div>
<div class="int d4"></div>
</div>
```

Однако Jsoup распарсивает его так:

```html
<div class="price">
<div class="int dash"></div>
<div class="int dash"></div>
<div class="int dot"></div>
<div class="int dash"></div>
<div class="int dash"></div
</div>
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Либо анализировать структуру запросов фронтенда и делать их из своего кода, либо использовать Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно парсить не сам сайт а данную [страницу](https://cheb.ru/api/azs-info.php)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]